Liquibase loadData changeset not repeatedly executing based on context
I’m working with Liquibase in a Gradle project and have a "loadData" changeset which loads data from a CSV file (including a column which has references to txt files which are stored as CLOB).
Here's the changeset:
<changeSet id="load-animal-data" author="myname" context="animals">
    <loadData
        file="path/to/data/animals.csv"
        tableName="animal_table"
        separator=","
        encoding="UTF-8"/
</changeSet>

And csv file:
id,description
1,./path/to/data/animal1.txt
2,./path/to/data/animal2.txt
...

Data is loaded properly while having the runAlways="true" property. But I would like to minimise the liquibase update time and execute the changeset only when necessary (when I know that changes were made in txt files).
Atribute "runOnChange" doesn't solve this problem as changes are happening in txt files, not within the csv file. Liquibase doesn't "look" further into the referenced files.
Had an idea to control the execution of the "load-animal-data" changeset by providing a special context "animals". But it seems that liquibase will execute it once, mark it in DATABASECHANGELOG as executed, and ignore in future.
Is there a way to control the execution of the loadData changeset just by context? Or any other approach to achieve repeated execution while avoiding the execution on every update?
